# Repairing sliding glass doors

Tags: sliding-glass-door

Had sliding glass door installed and I think they used the wrong spray foam because the door is bowed and doesn't slide properly. Is it repairable or will I have to get a new door?

Comment: Photos would help.

Comment: Do you mean that the frame is bowed? Is it the vertical stiles that are bowed or the header or the lower sill and track?